# Ant not recognizing variables upon build

Tags: xml, variables, ant

prefacing this by saying I've never used Ant, or XML, and am currently learning how to use it. When utilizing hardcoded directories, the build worked fine, but once I introduced variables, it started causing some problems...

Here's my build.xml as it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="builder" default="main">
    <property name="message" value="Building the .jar file." />
    <property name="java-dir" value="src" description="java directory" />
    <property name="txt-dir" value="text" description="text directory" />
    <property name="javadoc-dir" value="docs" description="javadoc directory" />
    <property name="jar-dir" value="bin" description="jar directory" />
    <property name="class-dir" value="classes" description="class directory" />

    <target name="main" depends="compile">
        <echo>
            $(message)
        </echo>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="document">
        <javac srcdir="$(java-dir)" destdir="$(class-dir)" />
    </target>
    <target name="compress">
        <jar jarfile="$(jar-dir)/Main.jar" 
             manifest="$(txt-dir)/manifest.txt" 
             basedir="$(jar-dir)" 
             includes="$(class-dir)/*.class" />
    </target>
    <target name="document" depends="compress">
        <javadoc sourcefiles="$(jar-dir)/Builder.java" destdir="$(javadoc-dir)">
        </javadoc>
    </target>
</project>
```

And here is what I get upon running `Ant` on the Unix terminal.

```
BUILD FAILED
/users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/build.xml:22: Manifest file: /users/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/REDACTED/$(txt-dir)/manifest.txt does not exist.
```

As you might be able to see, `$(txt-dir)/manifest.txt` appears rather than `text/manifest.txt`. I've tried searching a bit, but I can't seem to find any reasons why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: You need curly brackets {}, not round (): e.g. ${java-dir}, to reference and use the value of an Ant property, otherwise the "raw" value, in this case "$(java-dir)" is used.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [martin clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183172/martin-clayton) in the comment there, curly brackets are utilized rather than round brackets! My lecturer had the wrong brackets in his slides. Thank you!